# How do I stop my script when I click cancel on a popup box?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to stop my script when the user clicks cancel on a certain popup box. Part of the script goes as follows:

```
$OS = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).caption

if ($OS -ne "Microsoft Windows 10 *"){

   $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("This computer is currently running $OS. To continue with the 
script click OK, otherwise click Cancel.",0,"Windows 10 
Notification",0x1)

}
```

That is where the user has to decide to terminate the script progress or continue. And I need to be able to continue the script when the user clicks OK, but stop the script from continuing when he clicks Cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can capture the popup answer in a variable and use an `if-statement` to stop the script with `Break`. Try using this:

```
$OS = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).caption

if ($OS -ne "Microsoft Windows 10 *"){

    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $answer = $wshell.Popup("This computer is currently running $OS. To continue with the 
    script click OK, otherwise click Cancel.",0,"Windows 10 
    Notification",0x1)

    if($answer -eq 2){Break}

}
```

`$answer` shows as **1** for OK and **2** for Cancel

Comment: Can I make it a continue or cancel button, instead of OK and cancel? How do I do that?

Comment: I dont believe you can do this using the `wscript.shell` object but you can do a combination of try again continue or cancel just change `0x1` to `0x6`. If you want to know more about it you can go to this page [Popup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f.aspx). It tells you all the options available for changing the buttons... If you want to add a notification dialog with info you can go to [yellow dialog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730952.aspx) an this gives you info on how to do that.

Comment: I used `0x4` for Yes and No buttons, but when I wrote: `if($answer -eq 2){exit}` to terminate if the user clicks no, the script didn't exit. Any ideas?

Comment: in that case `Yes= 6` and `No = 7`. so you would have to change it to `if($answer -eq 7){exit}`... to see which number correlates to which option take off `$answer` and you will see a number appear on the powershell window after execution is complete or just go the website I sent you and you will see the return values listed for each under the section called `Return Values`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using Windows Forms and updated the script accordingly. You can find more examples [here](http://powershell-tips.blogspot.de/2012/02/display-messagebox-with-powershell.html).

I also changed the if condition because you where checking if the variable `$OS` was **exactly** `"Microsoft Windows 10 *"`; to check if it **begins** with the string use `-notlike` instead of `-ne`.

```
$OS = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).caption

if ($OS -notlike "Microsoft Windows 10 *") {
    $PopupTitle = "Windows 10 Notification"
    $PopupMessage = "This computer is currently running $OS. To continue with the script click OK, otherwise click Cancel."
    $PopupOptions = "OkCancel"
    $PopupAnswer = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($PopupMessage,$PopupTitle,$PopupOptions,[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation)

    if ($PopupAnswer -eq "Cancel") {
        Break
    }
}
```

Comment: I was checking if $OS was "Microsoft Windows 10 *". Note the asterisk as a wildcard for any device running any version of Windows 10.